# Folland real analysis, Proposition 2.20

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's real analysis, Proposition 2.20 states

> If $f\in L^{+}$ and $\int f < \infty$ then $\{x:f(x) = \infty\}$ is a null set and $\{x:f(x) > 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

May I ask how to prove "$\{x:f(x) > 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite"? One attempt was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520079/if-f-in-l-and-int-f-infty-then-there-exists-a-null-set-and-a-sigma), which says

> Set $\{x:f(x) > 0\} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{f(x) > 1/n\}$. For each $n$, set $\phi_n = \frac{1}{n}1_{\{f(x) > 1/n\}}$ with $0\leq \phi_n \leq f$, so $$\int f \geq \int \phi_n = \frac{1}{n}\mu(\{f(x) > 1/n\})$$ Thus, $$n\int f \geq \mu(\{f(x) > 1/n\})$$ Since, $0\leq \mu(\{f(x) > 1/n\}) \leq n\int f < \infty \ \ \forall n$ so $\{x:f(x) > 0 \}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

I do not understand why "$n\int f$ is finite for any $n$". What if $n\to\infty$? Thanks!

Comment: Since $\int f <+\infty$, for each **fixed** $n$, $n \int f < +\infty$.  

So, for each **fixed** $n$, $\mu(\{f(x) > 1/n\}) < +\infty$, which is all we need to prove.  

Of course, as $n \to \infty$, we have that $n \int f  \to \infty$ and $\mu(\{f(x) > 1/n\})$ increases and may even to $+\infty$. But this is not a problem.

Comment: **Attention**: Since $\{x: f(x) > 1/n\}$ is an increasing sequence of sets,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \{x: f(x) > 1/n\}$  is well-defined, and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \{x: f(x) > 1/n\} = \{x: f(x) > 0\} $$

and, by a theorem in Measure Theory, we have 

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{x: f(x) > 1/n\}) = \mu(\{x: f(x) > 0\}) $$

So, since $\mu(\{x : f(x) > 1/n\})$ increases (as $n$ increases) and may even go to $+\infty$ (as $n \to \infty$), we have that $\mu(\{x: f(x) > 0\})$ may be $+\infty$, but $\{x: f(x) > 0\}$ remains $\sigma$-finite.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $n\int f\to\infty $ as $n\to \infty$. But all we have to show is each $E_n = \{x,\: f(x)>n^{-1}\}$ has finite measure,

$$
\mu(E_n)\leq n\int f<+\infty
$$

and we can write

$$
\underbrace{\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\overbrace{E_n}^{\substack{\text{finite}\\\text{measure}}}}_{\substack{\text{no restriction}\\\text{on measure}}} = \Biggl\{x,\: f(x) > 0\Biggr\}
$$

The idea of $\sigma$-finiteness is that we can decompose the space into countably many chunks of finite measure, (even though the entire space might not have finite measure). Some motivation for $\sigma$-finiteness: allows us to subtract sets on $E_n$, among other things.

Comment: I understand that for finite $n$, $E_n$ has finite measure, but why does $n\int f < \infty$ hold for $n\to\infty$? (We need to show the inequality hold for any $n$, both finite and infinite, right?) I'm probably misunderstanding something...Please feel free to point it out. Thanks!

Comment: We wish to show each of the sets $E_n$ have finite measure. It is similar to how the natural numbers consists only of finite numbers, yet $n\to\infty$. 

$\sigma$-finiteness only requires us to show there exists countably many, sets of finite measure that make up the union. But the union itself does not have to be of finite measure.

Comment: I guess you mean: $E_1$, $E_2$, $E_3$, ... all have finite measure, i.e., $E_n$ has finite measure for n = 1, 2, 3... Their union does not need to have finite measure - which I agree. I'm basically confused about why $E_{\infty}$ has finite measure. $\sigma$-finiteness requires each $E_n$ to have finite measure, right?

Comment: If we define $E_\infty = \bigcup E_n$, then it is not required to have finite measure. Only the individual pieces that make up $E_\infty$ are required to have finite measure. 


To: "We need to show the inequality hold for any , both finite and infinite, right?", no we only have to consider finite $n$.

Comment: I thought you defined $E_n = \{x: f(x) > 1/n\}$, so should $E_{\infty}$ be $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{x: f(x) > 1/n\}$ instead? To "We need to show inequality hold for any , both finite and infinite, right?", I thought we should consider the case where $n\to\infty$ because as you mentioned, $\sigma$-finiteness requires us to show there exists **countably** many sets of finite measure that make up the union.

Comment: In general, we cannot take limits of sets. We can take limits of *measures* of sets (which are treated like real-valued sequences in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. But the object 

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\{x,\: f(x)>n^{-1}\}
$$

is not defined. You might be confusing countable unions with Theorem 1.8, let me know if you still have doubts.

Comment: I think in essence my question is: $f(n) := a\times n$ where $a<\infty$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is $f(n)$ finite for any $n$?

Comment: @sam2018 Yes it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! : )

Comment: @Qqqq123123 ,  Since $\{x: f(x) > 1/n\}$ is an increasing sequence of sets,
the object $\lim_{n \to \infty} \{x: f(x) > 1/n\}$  is, in fact,  well-defined, and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \{x: f(x) > 1/n\} = \{x: f(x) > 0\} $$