# $f \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$, then is $f$ finite for any $n$?

Tags: real-analysis

It looks like a trivial question but I'm having difficulty in understanding:

> $f(n)=a \times n $ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a < \infty$, and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is $f(n)$ finite for any $n$?

If yes, why? (I'm puzzled when $n\to\infty$)

If no, then could you help me with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724948/folland-real-analysis-proposition-2-20) question, where I'm confused about a step in a proof that seems to claim "yes" for the above question.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  Obviously $a\times n$ is finite if both $a,n$ are real numbers.

Comment: I think you can see this by considering simply $f(n)=2n.$ For any *particular* value of $n,$ the function value $f(n)=2n$ is indeed finite. [any particular number is finite.] But as we increase n to toward infinity the output $2n$ also increases toward infinity.

Comment: $\infty \notin \Bbb R$, so $a\in\Bbb R$ already says $a < \infty$. For the same reason, $n \in \Bbb N$ also means $n < \infty$, and so $an < \infty$. When we talk about $n\to\infty$, we are not talking about a single value of $n$. Instead we are talking about how $f(n)$ changes when we change the value of $n$ - specifically, when the size of $n$ increases. And even then $n$ never actually takes on the value $\infty$. $n\to \infty$ just means there is no upper limit on the values of $n$ we are investigating. But each of those values of $n$, and of $a$ are finite.